# Android Studio Emulator is messed up

Tags: android, android-studio

UI in the emulator on my android studio is broken. The icons and fonts are messed up
[image]

[image]

Comment: wipe it and make a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It crashes sometimes. First, make sure to `Close` your `Emulator` otherwise it throws an error. Just go to `Device Manager` as shown below the image.
[image]

and then `Select` on more [image] options of your messed Emulator(Crashed Emulator) as below an image. Click on `Cold Boot Now`.

[image]

and wait until your device Manager `Reboot` your Emulator. It'll safely reboot your emulator. If the issue is not solved yet, let me know.

EDIT 1: Improved formatting